# iOS: Swipe gesture works sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have added a swipe gesture on label programatically.

```
swipe = 
[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer:)];
    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.discountLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.discountLabel addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

But what happens is when I try to swipe on label, on first 3-4 swipes it does not work, suddenly on another attempt it works. Swipe is not smooth. I have also included

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

My view hierarchy is,

```
---> View 
 |
---> SubView - A 
 |
---> SubView - B
 |
---> Label
```

Label is the one on which I have to apply the swipe, what is exact issue ? how to resolve ?

Comment: try to find the issue by always allowing this property called setUserInteractionEnabled:YES in the xib

Comment: may be userinteraction is the problem

Comment: No. None of above worked.

Comment: Show your code, it is hard to reproduce.